# Powershell workflows, installing software locally after disabling UAC?

Tags: powershell

So I'm bored and trying to learn about WorkFlows in Powershell but somethings just not clicking. So I've got a script that prompts for admin creds to open a new POSH window, then makes the registry changes to disable UAC (only for the duration of the script), then called some exe and MSI installers located on a mapped drive.

```bsh
import-module ActiveDirectory
$erroractionpreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

#Elevate running of script to Administrative
param([switch]$Elevated)
function Check-Admin {
$currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
$currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}
if ((Check-Admin) -eq $false)  {
if ($elevated)
{
# could not elevate, quit
}
 
else {
 
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
}
exit
}

#Workflow to restart the pc

Workflow reboot_and_continue {


#The following section allows for changing the UAC settings for the duration of the script
{
New-Variable -Name Key 
New-Variable -Name PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name 
New-Variable -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name 
 
Function Set-RegistryValue($key, $name, $value, $type="Dword") {  
  If ((Test-Path -Path $key) -Eq $false) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $key | Out-Null }  
       Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $name -Value $value -Type $type  
}  
 
Function Get-RegistryValue($key, $value) {  
   (Get-ItemProperty $key $value).$value  
}  
 
$Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" 
$ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name = "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" 
$PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name = "PromptOnSecureDesktop" 
 
Function Get-UACLevel(){ 
    $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = Get-RegistryValue $Key $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name 
    $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = Get-RegistryValue $Key $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name 
    If($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 0 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 0){ 
        "Never notIfy" 
    } 
    ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 5 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 0){ 
        "NotIfy me only when apps try to make changes to my computer(do not dim my desktop)" 
    } 
    ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 5 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 1){ 
        "NotIfy me only when apps try to make changes to my computer(default)" 
    } 
    ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 2 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 1){ 
        "Always notIfy" 
    } 
    Else{ 
        "Unknown" 
    } 
} 
     
Function Set-UACLevel() { 
    Param([int]$Level= 2) 
 
    New-Variable -Name PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value 
    New-Variable -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value 
 
    If($Level -In 0, 1, 2, 3) { 
        $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 5 
        $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 1 
        Switch ($Level)  
        {  
          0 { 
              $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 0  
              $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 0 
          }  
          1 { 
              $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 5  
              $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 0 
          }  
          2 { 
              $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 5  
              $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 1 
          }  
          3 { 
              $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 2  
              $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 1 
          }  
        } 
        Set-RegistryValue -Key $Key -Name $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name -Value $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value 
        Set-RegistryValue -Key $Key -Name $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name -Value $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value 
 
        Get-UACLevel 
    } 
    Else{ 
        "No supported level" 
    } 
     
} 
 
Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-UACLevel 
Export-ModuleMember -Function Set-UACLevel
}

set-uaclevel 0



#This section calls the installers from a network share and runs them locally


Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "g:\IT\software\ChromeSetup.exe" -ArgumentList "/s" -Wait }
if ($setup.exitcode -eq 0)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "g:\IT\support\NSG_Vipre_agent_ssi-mi.msi" -ArgumentList "-silent" -Wait }
if ($setup.exitcode -eq 0)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "G:\IT\software\spiceworks\install_collection.bat" -Wait }
if ($setup.exitcode -eq 0)
```

Line 25 is where I'm thinking of trying to introduce the work flow.. but on second thought it might be better to encompass the entire thing in the workflow... I just don't know.

I've tried searching but I just can't find any examples of how to install software using a workflow.  the idea is to run a powershell window with admin creds, disabled UAC then reboot. Once started back up call the various installers then re-enable UAC and reboot again.
Thanks!

Comment: Note that Windows PowerShell workflows were introduced in v3, but never really took off. Given that they're no longer available in PowerShell [Core] v6+, where all future development effort will go, I think it's fair to call it an obsolescent technology.

Comment: Oh wow.. all the reading about Workflows yesterday I did not see anything like this.  To be honest I'm not looking for super longevity here. If they are supported in Win10 for the next year at least I'll be happy.  Unless you know of another method?

Comment: The [PowerShell Core announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/) lists Workflows among the technologies no longer supported. While the individual technologies are not identified with respect to whether they are dead for good or _may_ return, you can infer that Workflows are dead from the fact that [a deliberate decision was made not to port the underlying technology, WF (Windows Workflow Foundation), to .NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/supporting-the-community-with-wf-and-wcf-oss-projects/).

Comment: (The above was just to better support the obsolescence claim.) As for alternatives: I've never used Workflows myself, but perhaps [this post](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/alternative-to-powershell-workflow/) provides pointers.

Comment: Understood and thanks for the info. Guess I'll figure something else out for this.  I found a site that explains how to possible bypass UAC programmatically that looks promising: http://woshub.com/run-program-without-admin-password-and-bypass-uac-prompt/